# Is there a fast plotting library in R (hopefully usable in combination with shiny)?

Tags: r, plot

I plot quiet a lot of plots in R for an interactive website and typically use ggplot for that, also thanks to its amazing interactivity with shiny. However, it needs really long to load pictures with more than 2000 points.

In the past I worked in the Python world with dash and bokeh and both are combinable with datashader which allows to plot millions of points in a fraction of a second and still have interactivity (you can brush over plots and react to that etc).
https://datashader.org/getting_started/Interactivity.html

Is there a way to have this speed also in a shiny-app (or in R in general)?

Comment: You could use a JS plotting library like D3 to handle the rendering

Comment: if you're impressed using bokeh with python, have you tried using [`rbokeh`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbokeh/index.html)?

Comment: Why not use python version shiny for your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried highcharter library? It is a wrapper for JS Highcharts library
https://jkunst.com/highcharter/